# How to compute a median and percentiles in numpy on summarised (observation, number_of_responses) data?

Tags: numpy, median, percentile

The documented percentile and median methods work on raw, unprocessed data:

```
raw_data = [1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5]  # observations

a = np.array(raw_data)
np.median(a)

a = np.array(raw_data)
np.percentile(a, 50)
```

How to achieve the same outcome using `summarized_data` such as below (**without expanding it first**):

```
summarised_data = [[1,4],[2,1],[3,1],[4,2],[5,2]]  # [[observation, number_of_responses], [...]]
```

**That is, without performing the equivalent of:**

```
data = [n for i in range(len(summarised_data)) for n in [summarised_data[i][0]] * summarised_data[i][1]]
```

Comment: medians are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601872/numpy-or-scipy-to-calculate-weighted-median

Comment: Seems like you're asking to find the median given a histogram with bins of size 1.  This may help, but frankly might be more work than the "expanding" you're talking about.  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/879052