# How to calculate weighted Median for every subarray in 2d matrice?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, statistics, median

This question is a new one (I've already looked into similar questions and did not find what I need). Therefore:

What is the most efficient way to apply a weighted median to every subarray of a 2d `numpy` matrix efficiently? (No extra frameworks, but pure `numpy` if possible)

```
Data = np.asarray([[ 1.1,  7.8,  3.3, 4.9],
[ 6.1,  9.8,  5.3, 7.9],
[ 4.1,  4.8,  3.3, 7.1],
... 
[ 1.1,  7.4,  3.1, 4.9],
[ 7.1,  3.8,  7.3, 8.1],
[ 19.1,  2.8,  3.2, 1.1]])

weights = [0.64, 0.79, 0.91, 0]
```

**Note:** the answers to the other questions only show an 1d problem. This problem hast to deal with **1.000.000** subarrays efficiently

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood what "weighted median" is. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601872/numpy-or-scipy-to-calculate-weighted-median) came up when I looked up for the meaning of weighted median.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Data` provided by @JoonyoungPark, you can use a list comprehension:

```
[np.median(i*weights) for i in Data]

[1.8535000000000001,
 4.3635,
 2.8135,
 1.7625000000000002,
 3.7729999999999997,
 2.5620000000000003]
```

Comment: Edit: are you sure this is the 'weighted median'? actually, by weighted, the weights in terms of percentile is meant. (correct me if I'm wrong or if the result would be the same)